# Drawing black areas in matlab contourf plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am generating a series of plots using matlab `contourf`. I need to do the following with the resulting figure. From this state:

[image]

Make this:

[image]

**Important note:** I know the coordinates of pixels which should be blackened.

The easiest way is possible to use `ind2rgb`, do the "blackening" manually, then use `imagesc` and deal with the axes propeerties. But using this I will lose the `contourf` graphics (e.g. the contour lines).

Any better ideas?

Comment: Oh, nice one! Thanks a lot! I have never met that but it should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the figure colormap by adding black color to the one you use.

M=colormap;
M=[0,0,0 ; M];
colormap(M)

Now assign to the "should be black" pixels a value smaller than the minimum. This will map this value to the minimum color which is now black.

To assign the value efficiently use subs2ind

Comment: It's elegant, thanks a lot, but the patch is more useful.